# Select password field and show it in textbox by criteria

Tags: c#, sql

I have a windows form with 4 textbox fields: username, question, date of birth, and password.

I want to load and display the password from the database table if the entered informations are correct (username, question and dateOfBirth textbox) and the OK button is pressed.

```
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
        SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select PassWord from dbo.Admin where UserName = '" + this.UserName.Text + "' and Question= '" + this.Question.Text + "' and DateOfBirth= '" + this.DateOfBirth.Text + "';", myConn);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        myConn.Open();
        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        PassShow.Text = myReader["PassWord"].ToString();
        myConn.Close();
```

I use VS 2015, writing this in c# with db from VS.

I have this error when i debug it: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: Please don't store passwords in clear text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to return one row and one column, use this instead:

```
PassShow.Text = SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();
```

Otherwise you have to check if the reader got any result rows before you can access them savely:

```
using (SqlDataReader myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (myReader.HasRows && myReader.Read())
        PassShow.Text = myReader.GetString("PassWord");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (myReader.HasRows && myReader.Read())
        {
            PassShow.Text = (myReader["PassWord"].ToString());
        }
        myConn.Close();
```